# TextSearch not returning output (but URL is valid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

```
function getCoffeeLatLon(inpLat, inpLon){
    var searchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=coffee&key=AIzaSyCKY43b8fpjLUuagtq1ZdSc477QwFuprew&location=15.7228486,-90.2348";
    var firstLat;
    var firstLon;
    var firstName;
    var fullJSON= $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=coffee&key=AIzaSyCKY43b8fpjLUuagtq1ZdSc477QwFuprew&location=15.7228486,-90.2348", function(data){
                                            firstLat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;  
                                            firstLon = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng; 
                                            firstName = data.results[0].name;
                                            console.log("checking");
                                            });

    var coffeeLatLonName = [firstLat, firstLon, firstName];
    return coffeeLatLonName;
  }
```

Above is my code sample. While I can access the Google Maps API URL online and see the full JSON results, when using it in my code, it will not run the 'sucess' function of my $.getJSON call. I can also save the results of the URL and use that file without issue.

Why can't I use the URL directly in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: I can help us, please send full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run [your code (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4aqhso3z/), I get a javascript error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=coffee&key=AIzaSyCKY43b8fpjLUuagtq1ZdSc477QwFuprew&location=15.7228486,-90.2348. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If you want to access the places API text search from javascript, use the [Places Library of the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go now.